# Swipe between tabs when the layouts are the same

Tags: android

I want to add two tabs to my Android app.

- Tab 1: To do tasks
- Tab 2: Done tasks

The layout in both views is the same (the only thing changing is the data shown). It's a gridlayout with cardviews.

How can I implement the tab/swipe action that changes from one to another being both the same .xml?

Android documentation is outdated and many of the methods used [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) are deprecated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Comment: You can just use 2 fragments with the same xml.

Comment: Add tabs using TabLayout and Use ViewPagerAdapter and add your fragments for each tab in ViewPagerAdapter and code whatever do you want to perform in each fragment with or without same layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **viewPager** and **tabLayout** for that swipefeature and call your fragments through custom adapter by extanding FragmentPagerAdapter in that
.